# Roll back upgrade

Tags: updates

Laptop Dell Latitude E7440, Ubuntu 20.10, Gnome 3.38.3, automatic updates enabled to run every 24h.

Always worked like a charm, fast and responsive. But, some update(s) must have installed during the night, because today it takes roughly 45 seconds to open Settings, or a folder. Chromes starts in about 2 minutes.

Something definitely happened, but how do I find out what? And how do I roll back performed updates? Googled it and got a tip re. Synaptic, but that's not present on my system.

I've tried multiple reboots, checking performance (which shows no weird stuff as far as i can tell, cpu on 15-20%, memory as well).

Help!

Comment: Apt keeps logs in `/var/log/apt/history.log` which should tell you when packages were installed/upgraded (*deb* packages anyway), but how are we to know what *fs* or backup strategy you've put in place, thus what rollback functions you have available?

Comment: So your question is "programs open slowly (we must assume they were quicker before), system thrash 15-20% cpu, memory OK"?

Comment: I got suddenly Firefox to start extremely slow (since a few days): instead of the normal almost instantaneous, now it takes like 6-7 seconds. But I believe the solution is not a rollback; I hope this will get caught and fixed in a near future update.